# For a given $N$ and a given prime $p_j$, count number of numbers that you can generate in ($N^{0.5}$, $N/p_j$] not divisible by any primes $ \ge p_j$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-number-theory

For a given $N$ and a given prime $p_j$
count the number of numbers can you generate in ($N^{0.5}$,  $N/p_j$]
that are not divisible by any primes $ \ge p_j$

**Example:**
$N=100, p_j=5$

you can generate two numbers i.e. $12$ and $18$

ie $12=2^2.3$

ie $18=2.3^2$

Both the above numbers lie in (10,20]

Hence the answer is $2$.

**My idea so far:**

if $p_j>N^{0.5}$ answer is always $0$.

**Step 1.**
Shortlist all numbers $a \le N^{0.5}$ such that $a$ is only divisble by primes less than $p_j$.

**Step 2.**
Increment powers of each prime factor gradually to reach the desired range
for eample in above exmaples if $a=2.3$.
I can increment powers of $2$ and test for how many powers of $2$ keep it is in $(10,20]$. This can be done in $O(1)$.
Similarly I can do for $3$ as well.

The tricky cases arise when the power of multiple prime factors can be incremented simultaneously to generate a valid candidate. So this approach is going to be tricker for large ranges as it can have many prime factors.

Comment: The problem is not clear to me.  What does "you can generate" mean?  What determines whether you consider that a number can or can't be generated?  Are  you asking to count the number of [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) in a particular range?

Comment: @D.W. possibly "that you can generate"="that exists"